# Any way to get dir entries without changing atime in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux

It looks Dir.entries("dir") updates the dir's atime on Linux.

```
irb(main):042:0> File::Stat.new("/tmp/tmp2").atime
=> Thu Aug 25 09:16:36 -0700 2011
irb(main):043:0> File::Stat.new("/tmp/tmp2").atime
=> Thu Aug 25 09:16:36 -0700 2011
irb(main):044:0> Dir.entries("/tmp/tmp2")
=> ["file1", "..", ".", "dir1"]
irb(main):045:0> File::Stat.new("/tmp/tmp2").atime
=> Thu Aug 25 09:16:49 -0700 2011
```

Is it possible to get the dir entries without changing the atime of itself in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it in Ruby, or even in general. Reading any file or directory, by any method, will always update its atime. (Unless the whole filesystem is set to not use atimes with a mount flag, like `noatime` or `relatime`.)